# Home game - player not in hand influencing players decisions. Is this against the rules?

Tags: rules, etiquette

Home game. Started with 6 players, down to the final 2 heads up. Me and someone else. I’m small blind. I’ve just called the big blind. One of the guys who went out earlier “jokingly” says to big blind “go all in”.

I’ve told him that he shouldn’t be saying that. He says he’s bantering. I said I have no problem with table banter (even though he’s not in the hand!) but that what he’s saying could influence a players decision. He didn’t like me saying that and a disagreement ensued. Am I wrong for asking him to not say things like “Go all in?”. I think it’s shocking that he thinks this is ok. Against the rules? Bad etiquette?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In any casino poker room, the non-player would be warned "one player to a hand". If he continues, both he and the player he is advising may be ejected.

Comment: depends on how much you're playing for..

Comment: It does not answer your question. (I agree with the answer Jon gave.) But this exact situation is my biggest "pet peeve" with Holdem. A big part of the time there are several people hanging around until the final winner is selected, they get bored, and they want to "help."

Answer (score 2):

yes this is generally against the rules, the player should be warned, and if he keeps to it, uninvite him from your game.